# Help with a infinite geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series

My professor wants us to solve this infinite series in terms of $\phi$ and i. However, I have not worked with infinite series, or series in general, in several years. He mentioned using the geometric formula but I am not sure how to apply that here. Could someone help me start this?

$\sum_{k=i+1}^\infty \phi^{2k} (\phi^{-1} - \phi^{i})^2 $ given $ |\phi| < 1$

Comment: what did you tried until now?

Comment: First, compute the common ratio $r$ and the initial term $a$. You can find the initial term $a$ by plugging in $k = i + 1$ into the sum term (giving you an expression in terms of $i$ and $\phi$. You can find the common ratio by dividing the $(k+1)$th term by the $k$th term, which should simplify away all the $k$s (otherwise the series is not geometric!). Or, if you trust that it is geometric, divide the second term by the initial term $a$. Then, simply compute $\frac{a}{1 - r}$. The sum formula works when $|r| < 1$. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$a+ap+ap^2+...=\frac{a}{1-p},|p|<1$$

try to adjust the terms so you can get a infinite geometric progression.